# elastic range query working on staging but not on dev or qa

Tags: elasticsearch

the below is my query
working on my staging environment but not on dev or qa. all the configurations are same i guess. any help?
get /tenant_candidate/docs/_search

```
{
  "from": "0",
  "size": "300",
  "query": {
      
    "bool": {
        
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "entityType": "candidate"
          }
        },
        
        {
          "range": {
            "record.totalExpInMonths": {
              "gte": 100,
              "lte": 120
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "record.createdDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Share ES version, mapping & error